# HTML when we attach image

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-blog/assets/f3a16fb6.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-blog/assets/ninja_zpsa5dbe37a.jpg"/>

</body>
```

even though both the image are showing when I try to save the code its showing an error.

Can anyone help me with it.

Thank you

Comment: What error do you speak of?

Comment: What do you mean by "save the code"?

Comment: i'm practising HTML on Code Academy and this was an exercise when I entered the image url the image is showing in the window but when I try to save and submit the code its showing an error. and it just says error and try again.

Comment: hey thanks guys appreciate your help the problem was i did not added space while closing the second image tag.

Answer (score 1):

The only error in your HTML I see, is the missing closing HTML-Tag. Perhaps your "Code Academy" environment is very "picky" and sensible to these kind of errors a classic browser would ignore.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-blog/assets/f3a16fb6.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-blog/assets/ninja_zpsa5dbe37a.jpg"/>
  </body>
</html>
```